# assertEqual transforms a value into None

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I'm very disturbed by this error. Here is some context

I have a Challenge model

```python
class Challenge(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Member, related_name="challenge_author")
    category = models.ForeignKey(ChallengeCategory)
    rank = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    validations = models.ManyToManyField(Member,
                                         through=Validation,
                                         related_name="validated_users",
                                         blank=True)
    def update_rank(self):
        ranks = [0 if validation.rank is None else int(validation.rank)
                 for validation
                 in Validation.objects.filter(challenge__pk=self.id,)]
        self.rank = sum(ranks)/len(ranks)
        self.save()
```

And I have a test to test `update_rank()`

```python
def test_update_rank(self):
    hello_world = Challenge.objects.get(name="HelloWorld")
    hello_world.update_rank()
    print(hello_world.rank == 9.00)
    self.assertEqual(hello_world.rank, 9.00)
```

When I run the test, I get :

```
True

Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../website/tests/test_models.py", line 105, in test_update_validation
    self.assertEqual(hello_world.rank, 9.00)
AssertionError: None != 9
```

So it means that `hello_world.rank` **is** equal to `9.00` according to the `print()` but for some reasons, `assertEqual` thinks that `hello_world.rank` is `None`

I don't know what to think. If you need more information, please do not hesitate.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: please, add `test_update_validation` method, not `test_update_rank`

Comment: Hey, yes, that's my silly mistake. After spending too much time coding, I didn't notice that it was `test_update_validation` that was failing... Do not laugh, please :D Thank you though !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the traceback, the `test_update_validation` method is failing, not the `test_update_rank` which you've presented.

Comment: I think I spent like 1h trying some weird testing, weird conditions. I feel so silly. Thank you for saving my day !